# How to add AssetCode to to a CfnFunction class

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am wanting to be able to create a CfnFunction, but be able to pass in an AssetCode class for the `code` parameter. Normally, using the higher level `Function` construct provided by `aws_cdk.aws_lambda`, this would suffice:

```py
class MyFunction(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope, id, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        self._python_function = Function(
            self,
            id="PythonFunction",
            runtime=Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
            handler="app.main.lambda_handler",
            timeout=Duration.minutes(3),
            code=Code.from_asset(
                path="/path/to/my/function",
                bundling=BundlingOptions(
                    image=Runtime.PYTHON_3_9.bundling_image,
                    command=[
                        "bash",
                        "-c",
                        "pip install -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output && cp -au . /asset-output",
                    ],
                ),
            ),
            memory_size=128,
            log_retention=RetentionDays.TWO_WEEKS,
        )
```

However, when trying to do that using the lower level CfnFunction construct, the documentation does not provide a clear example on how to pass in an AssetCode type:

```py
class MyFunctionWrapper(Stack):

    def __init__(
            self,
            scope,
            id,
            **kwargs,

    ):
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        code_asset: AssetCode = Code.from_asset(
            path="path/to/my/code",
            bundling=BundlingOptions(
                image=Runtime.PYTHON_3_9.bundling_image,
                command=[
                    "bash",
                    "-c",
                    "pip install -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output && cp -au . /asset-output",
                ],
            ),
        )

        self._role = Role(
            self,
            id=f"{id}FunctionRole",
            managed_policies=[
                ManagedPolicy.from_managed_policy_arn(
                    self,
                    id="PolicyArn",
                    managed_policy_arn="arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
                )
            ],
            assumed_by=ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
        )

        self._function = CfnFunction(
            self,
            id="Function",
            runtime="PYTHON_3_9",
            handler="app.handler",
            timeout=60,
            memory_size=128,
            role=self._role.role_name,
            code=code_asset,  # <- This is incorrect type for CfnFunction
        )

        self._log_group = LogGroup(
            self,
            id=f"{id}LogGroup",
            log_group_name=f"/aws/lambda/{self._function.function_name}",
            retention=RetentionDays.FIVE_DAYS,
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would choose to use `CfnFunction` over `Function`, but you can check out the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/v1.134.0/packages/@aws-cdk/aws-lambda/lib/function.ts#L685-L691) and see what it does. It passes the bucket and key through `code` after binding. Translated to Python it should look something like:

```
bound_code = code_asset.bind(self)

self._function = CfnFunction(
    self,
    id="Function",
    runtime="PYTHON_3_9",
    handler="app.handler",
    timeout=60,
    memory_size=128,
    role=self._role.role_name,
    code=CfnFunction.CodeProperty(
        s3_bucket=bound_code.s3_location.bucket_name,
        s3_key=bound_code.s3_location.object_key,
        s3_object_version=bound_code.s3_location.object_version,
    ),
)
```

Comment: The reason I would like to use the CfnFunction over the `Function` construct is because the `Function` construct creates a custom resource if the logRetention or logGroup properties are set: Note that, if either logRetention is set or logGroup property is called, a CloudFormation custom resource is added to the stack that pre-creates the log group as part of the stack deployment, if it already doesn’t exist, and sets the correct log retention period (never expire, by default).  That creates a custom resource composed of an IAM role, policy, and separate function to manage the log group.

Comment: Isn't it simpler to not set log retention?

Comment: Wouldn't that then keep the logs indefinitely instead of aging them off? Most use cases would want to have those logs age off after a set amount of time.

Comment: Ah, so you're specifying the log group yourself with the retention set on group itself. I wouldn't personally do that just to avoid a custom resource, but it should work. FYI [PythonFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda-python.PythonFunction.html) deals with `requirements.txt` too so even less to write.